# How to rename the files in the path with new different names in batch?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, rename

I have one file destination.txt with path information about my CDs:

```
 C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\Desktop\LOG Dateien CD Imaging\SME99.ISO
C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\Desktop\LOG Dateien CD Imaging\Biomasse.iso 
C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\Desktop\LOG Dateien CD Imaging\SAMPE36.ISO
```

Now I have to rename the ISOs with the numbers that are in the file PPN.txt one after another:

```
470692405 
394006801 
348117876
```

So it should be

```
SME99.ISO -> 470692405.ISO
Biomasse.iso -> 394006801.ISO
Sampe36.ISO -> 348117876.ISO
```

I have the following code for it:

```
< "PPN.txt"  (for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("destination.txt") do (
  set/P out="" & rename "%%a" "!out!%%~xa"
```

I want to modify the code that way that it works for the file destination.txt:

```
Success on: "C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\Desktop\LOG Dateien CD Imaging\SME99.ISO" 
Error on:   "C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\Desktop\LOG Dateien CD Imaging\Biomasse.iso" 
Success on: "C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\Desktop\LOG Dateien CD Imaging\SAMPE36.ISO"
```

If "Success on" stays before the path in destination.txt the image should be renamed as always only with the number from PPN.txt. 
But if "Error on" stays before the path in destination.txt the image should be renamed like this e_%number from PPN.txt%  . So it should be additional prefix e_ there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit** Batch now takes the prefix into account, splitting the lines from `destination.txt` at the colon into `%%A` and `%%B`

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
< "PPN.txt"  (
    for /F "usebackq tokens=1,* delims=:" %%A in ("destination.txt") do (
        Set "out="
        Set /P "out="
        Set "out=!out: =!"
        If /i "%%A" equ "Success on" (
            ren %%B "!out!.ISO" && echo Renamed %%B to "!out!.ISO" 
        ) Else If /i "%%A" equ "Error on" (
            ren %%B "e_!out!.ISO"  && echo Renamed %%B to "e_!out!.ISO" 
        ) Else (Echo unknown prefix "%%~A")
    ) 
)
```

Simulated ISO files returned this output:

```
Renamed  "C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\Desktop\LOG Dateien CD Imaging\SME99.ISO"  to "470692405.ISO"
Renamed    "C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\Desktop\LOG Dateien CD Imaging\Biomasse.iso"  to "e_394006801.ISO"
Renamed  "C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\Desktop\LOG Dateien CD Imaging\SAMPE36.ISO"  to "348117876.ISO"
```

Comment: Syntaxerror
Error on: "Success on: "C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\Desktop\LOG Dateien CD Imaging\SME99.ISO" "
Syntaxerror.
Syntaxfehler.
Error on: "Error on:   "C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\Desktop\LOG Dateien CD Imaging\Biomasse.iso" "
Syntaxerror.
Syntaxerror.
Error on: "Success on: "C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\Desktop\LOG Dateien CD Imaging\SAMPE36.ISO" "
Syntaxerror.

Comment: In your output it should be Error on: "C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\Desktop\LOG Dateien CD Imaging\Biomasse.iso "   instead of Success on

Comment: Sorry did some test with English and German user accounts and can't get the errors you describe, even if runnig the batch from powershell. Without echo I get errors like `The system cannot find the path specified.
Error on: "C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\Desktop\LOG Dateien CD Imaging\SME99.ISO"` The syntax error let's me assume there is an error on transfering the code. Did you copy and paste and save the batch as plain ascii?

Comment: yes, I made it all in ascii, but it's the same problem

Comment: What exact windows version do you use and what extension does the batch file have?

Comment: I use Windows 8.1 Pro and the batch file has .bat extension. It seems to me that there some problems with encoding quotes: maybe in destination.txt or in the batch

Comment: I scraped the files from this website and didn't have problems with it (using firefox on my up2date Win10pro).

Comment: The sense of the script is to recognize whether Error on or Success on stands before Path and dependent on this to rename the ISO in appropriate way. So we need a condition here instead of echo. Sorry, maybe I didn't define it clear enough in my question

Comment: It means that the file destination.txt already has Success on or Error on before path

Comment: Understood, see changed batch.

Comment: yes, that's it. But there is always one blank between the number and .iso after renaming e.g. e_394006801 .ISO  . Do you have any idea how to delete it?

Comment: The space stems presumably from the ppn.txt file, I changed the batch to remove it.

Comment: Instead of `ren %%B ...` I would write `ren "%%~B" ...` to always have proper quoting...

Comment: @aschipfl because %%B contains leading spaces the ~ wouldn't work. Ren wouldn't mind the spaces but for the ~ modifier it aren't outer quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
< PPN.txt (
  for /F "delims=" %%a in (destination.txt) do (
    set/P out="" & rename "%%a" "!out!%%~xa"&&echo Success on: "%%a"||(
      echo Error on:   "%%a" & rename "%%a" "e_!out!%%~xa"
    )
  )
)
```

`&&` will handle sucess of previous operations (`errorlevel` 0), `||` will handle failure.

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't renames. Are you sure that to variable %%a in the first line belongs only the path in " " without Success on: or Error on: ?

Comment: There is one closing parenthesis missing.

Comment: The third closing parenthesis leads to the syntax error

Comment: Yes, there was a missing parenthesis. Used your code without verifying!

Comment: Now I get an error message that "for %a in" can't be syntactically processed on this place